How do I change the background color of mat-mdc-form-field appearance="outline"
For some reason cant find a working example of how to override the background color when form field is outlined, all the examples work for filled

The controls are always transparent since you might switch from light and dark mode, so all you need is a custom CSS, that sets the background color to achieve the desired effect.
SCSS:
.custom-background .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
  background-color: azure;
}

HTML:
<p>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="custom-background">
    <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" />
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>

Stackblitz Demo
